# Trying to make background image scalable but it is still showing scrollable version on top

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to edit my website's main CSS file so that the background image doesn't move when you scroll down. I've tried a number of techniques, including the one listed below, but the problem is that the image still moves when scrolling from the top of the page...but once you reach the bottom of the image, the image appears again but at this point it becomes scalable and doesn't move when you keep scrolling down further (which is exactly what I want but I want it to be scalable from the very top of the page the whole way through). Just wondering what needs to be modified in the below code or if I need to look out for any special code in another section that might be causing this problem?

```
body { background: url(../img/pic.jpg) center fixed no-repeat; 
height:100%; width:100%;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover; 
padding:0; margin:0; text-align:center}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    background: url(../img/pic.jpg) center top no-repeat; 
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the problem persists - the background image is appearing at the top and then when you scroll down and reach the bottom of it, the image appears again but at that point it becomes 'fixed'. I just want to remove the top image so that it is fixed from top to bottom.

Comment: Can you set up an example jsfiddle to see? If you are unfamiliar with this, you can see it at jsfiddle.net and it should be fairly self explanatory from there.